# Cannot import manually placed node module with jsx

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

*Disclaimer: I am aware that the best way to retrieve node modules is through npm, this is a question to better understand a few things. Let me explain how i arrived to the issue at hand and what the issue is.*

---

I have two projects one called `SOMEAPP` and one called `COOLCOMPONENTPROJ`. They both use Create React App by FB.

On `SOMEAPP` I added a dependency on my package.json that points to a private bitbucket repo where my component is hosted so `SOMEAPP`'s package.json looks something like

```
   ...
   dependencies:{
      ...
      COOLCOMPONENTPROJ:"git+https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/COOLCOMPONENTPROJ.git"
      ...
   }
```

This works fine, i can see my code under `node_modules/coolcomponent`.

My `COOLCOMPONENT` project repo is (afaik) npm registry compliant and looks like so:

--**index.js**

```
let CoolComponent = <div>test</div>
export default CoolComponent
```

--**package.json**

```
{
  main:"index.js", <-- to my knowledge the important bit
  author:"blablah",
  ...more properties
}
```

---

### The issue

When importing `CoolComponent` on `SOMEAPP` like so:

`import CoolComponent from "COOLCOMPONENTPROJ"`

i get the following error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./node_modules/webchat-react-test/index.js Module parse failed:
>   Unexpected token (4:15) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type.

### The questions

Is it safe from this to assume that webpack doesnt transpile anything in the `node_modules` folder and therefore this is why this error comes up? I would assume so as only exporting pure js like `let a = 3; export default a;` in the same component works fine.

If so what is it that needs to be done? Should i build the project and then make sure my `index.js` imports the built file and exports that instead?

Comment: I was not able to find in CRA webpack configs but... you have to explicitly tell webpack to not apply babel-loader to node_modules, otherwise babel-loader will be applied to any .js file.

Comment: Im thinkin that it must be the case that CRA excludes all node_modules and this is why my component isnt transformed. Im thinking of ejecting only to take a better look at the webpack config. Hopefully i ll come back with the answer to this

Comment: you could also transpile your component before "publishing it", so it would reduce your future headaches.